# ElasticSearch search for empty fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have added a new nested object field to a elastic search index. I want to update the field with some default value like [ {"key": "xyz", "value": "val1"}]. I am trying to query the index where the field value is empty or null, but was not successful.

I have tried this

```
"bool": {
  "must_not": {
    "exists": {
      "field": "PropertyFields"
    }
  }
}
```

sample data

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "subjectPropertyFields": [
      {
        "value": "xyz",
        "key": "zzz"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2
  },
  {
    "Id": 3
  }
]
```

I want to query ids 2,3 .

Comment: can you please share some sample index data and expected search result ?

Comment: sample data , i want to query id's 2 and 3  [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "subjectPropertyFields": [
      {
        "value": "xyz",
        "key": "zzz"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2
  },
  {
    "Id": 3
  }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find documents that are missing a nested object field, you can use the `must_not` boolean query with the [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#find-docs-null-values).

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
  {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "subjectPropertyFields": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "subjectPropertyFields": [
      {
        "value": "xyz",
        "key": "zzz"
      }
    ]
  }
  {
    "Id": 2
  }
  {
    "Id": 3
  }
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "subjectPropertyFields",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "exists": {
                    "field": "subjectPropertyFields"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65047473",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "Id": 2
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65047473",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "Id": 3
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Ajay Kumar please go through my answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @Ajay Kumar thank u for accepting the answer, can you please upvote the answer as well :)

Comment: thank you , can you help me with the query if i need to add additional query like        isdata = true  and the existing query logic for the same .

Comment: @AjayKumar you can use a combination of bool query (with the match clause)  for the same, and it would be better if you can ask a separate question for the same with your new requirements :)

Comment: @AjayKumar does there exist a field in your document named `isdata` ?